# Deploy Play 2.x in Websphere 7

Tags: java, playframework, websphere

Somebody know if is possible to deploy a play 2.3.x app in IBM WebSphere 7 building a war file or something like that?

Comment: Specify the exact question you have, the words like 'something like that' do not describe the exact question.

Comment: ok, its possible to deploy the play 2.3.x app in websphere server 7 generating a war or ear file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, play can generate a WAR to run in an EE server and lists WAS 7 as an EE server that works.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/deployment

Comment: But that is possible in 1.2.x it is possible in its possible to deploy the play 2.3.x?

Answer (score 0):

But that is possible in 1.2.x it is possible in its possible to deploy the play 2.3.x?